# modifying the style of multiple elements via javascript's object properties

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname, object-properties

(Javascript) I stole this very nice code from another post here.
It changes the `style.backgroundColor` of those `div` elements with `.onmouseover`.

```
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>1</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>2</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>3</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>4</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>5</div>
<script>
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onmouseover = function() {
     this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
</script>
```

This works, but instead of doing it with `TagName` (that would mess up all of my other dozens of `div`), I would like to make it work with `id` (if it's even possibile) or with `className`.
 And without using the `html attributes`, all should be done through `object properties` inside the `<script>`.
It would be great if even the mighty `addEventListener` could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change `getElementsByTagName` to `getElementsByClassName`

here is the [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouLxkhvd/) and CODE -

```
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>1</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>2</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>3</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>4</div>
<div id='idEl' class='classEl'>5</div>
<script>
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("classEl");
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onmouseover = function() {
     this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     }
  }

</script>
```

**Note** - You are also missing a closing bracket `}` which i put in above code and you sre using same id's for every `div` which is incorrect because id's should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

To get elements by css class you can use the **getElementsByClassName** function

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classEl");
```

Note that it's better then using 'id' in your case because
html dose not allow multiple same ids on the same document.

To get element (not elements) you can:

```
document.getElementById("my_unique_id");
```

You can see working example - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t457s09y/)